# Using POST to fill Database through PHP and JSON - bug on Android

Tags: php, html, json, android-studio, post

I'm new here
I would like to get some help with my code.

I'm trying to send 6 strings using JSON Object to a database and its failed.
here is my android code:

```
        buttonsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    buttonsend.setText("Failed!");
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    parameters.put("name",TName.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("phone",TPhone.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("mail",TMail.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("A1",Q1Answer);
                    parameters.put("A2",Q2Answer);
                    parameters.put("A3",Q3Answer);

                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
}
```

here is my PHP Script (i have another script for the credentials):

```
    <?php

define('hostname', 'localdb');
define('user', 'sagisupr_qweasd');
define('password', 'sagisupr_qweasd');
define('databaseName', 'sagisupr_ppls');


$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, databaseName);
    $name = $_POST["name"]; 
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $mail = $_POST["mail"];
    $A1 = $_POST["A1"];
    $A2 = $_POST["A2"];
    $A3 = $_POST["A3"];

    $query = "Insert into ppls VALUES ('$name','$phone','$mail','$A1','$A2','$A3')";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);
echo 'HERE IS IT ! ';
?>
```

any idea why i get exepction ?\

here are some logs from android monitor:

```
    08-20 22:23:08.476 9694-9694/com.example.sagis.motor1 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
08-20 22:23:17.154 9694-9839/com.example.sagis.motor1 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-20 22:23:17.154 9694-9839/com.example.sagis.motor1 E/Volley: [306] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
                                                                    at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:476)
                                                                    at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:462)
                                                                    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:253)
                                                                    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:227)
                                                                    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
                                                                    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
                                                                    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

manifest permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

debug error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmHix.png)

Comment: What is your error? Is it in the DB or Android?

Comment: your error in php side or java?

Comment: it looks like your missing a comma in your insert statement.

Comment: the error is that I can't insert information into the database, in addition,i put some text change to the button when the execution occurs

Comment: it's not a comma i guess, the APP is running, just not filling information in the DB and i fixed the script in addition, thanks
but its not the issue

Comment: try to post your error, that way I'm not throwing darts in the dark. Also, if the fields in table ppls are not ordered in the same manner as your insert statement then it wont go through. If it is, are you using an auto incrementing primary key?

Comment: 08-20 22:23:17.154 9694-9839/com.example.sagis.motor1 E/Volley: [306] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you test your query directly in your database with some sample values in place of the variables?  What is your database table structure?  You know about prepared statements and placeholders for security, right?

Comment: i update main post

Comment: yes i have test that and its works fine

Comment: Have you tried to add the INTERNET permissions in your manifest? You would need to add android.permission.INTERNET. Also, is the url set?

Comment: yes I did (*updated*), and the URL is set correctly

Comment: i add the errors from debug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)